# How can I get the prefan parent of any child and then search for specific childs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example this is the structure of a prefab in hierarhcy :

```
Prefab1
   Child1
   Child2
   Child3
     Child4
   Child5
     Child6
     Child7
   Child8
```

For example I have a script attached to Child3 or any other child but let's say Child3 and I want to find the prefab parent of it and then to get and loop over all the childs of Prefab1 and get Child6 and Child7

Now Child6 and Child7 both tagged as "ThisChilds"
But since in the world in the hierarchy I have more tagged childs as "ThisChilds" I want to find childs 6 and 7 of this Prefab1 and not of other Prefabs in the world.

The reason is that I want to assign Child6 and Child7 in the script attached to Child3

The script in Child3 for example will be :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class GetChilds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Child6
    public GameObject Child7
```

But instead dragging this Childs manual in the editor I want to find them automatic and assign them in the Start() to Child6 and Child7 I can drag them manual but it will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find Prefab1, and if its root gameobject in the hierarchy then you can find it like

```
Gameobject rootGameobject = child3.transform.root.gameobject;
```

and then if you want to find any child of this gameobject you can use

```
Gameobject Child6 = rootGameobject.transform.Find("Child6");
Gameobject Child7 = rootGameobject.transform.Find("Child7");
```

Even you can find nested childs with like that

```
Gameobject Child67 = rootGameobject.transform.Find("Child6/Child67");
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct and clean way here in my eyes would be to **not use `Find` at all**.

Instead rather use a Component on your root object and reference everything via the Inspector you need like e.g.

```
public class YourController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject child3;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject child6;
    // etc whatever you need

    public GameObject Child3 => child3;
    public GameObject Child6 => child6;
}
```

and then in your child components do e.g.

```
public class Child3Component : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Best if you reference this already in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private YourController yourController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As fallback get in once on runtime
        if(!yourController) yourController = GetComponentInParent<YourController>();
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
         // Now access the references you need 
         Debug.Log(yourController.Child6.name);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse you would use some more meaningful names instead of `Child3` or `child6` ;)